# Volley second request return null

Tags: android, android-volley

The first request done successfully but second request in queue return null , when setting break point and start debugging the second request get it's value successfully

```
    class ListLoader extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,MerchantCategories[]>
{
    MerchantCategories[] data;
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
    @Override
    protected MerchantCategories[] doInBackground(Void... params) {
        Gson g = new Gson();
        gcm = GoogleCloudMessaging.getInstance(getApplicationContext());
        try {
            regid = gcm.register(PROJECT_NUMBER);
            String msg="";
            msg = "Device registered, registration ID=" + regid;
            Log.i("GCM",  msg);
            EgxServices.getJsonFrom("http://inareg.com/APIs/RegisterAndroidDevice?registrationID="+regid,(Activity) c);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        MerchantCategories[] categs=g.fromJson(EgxServices.getJsonFrom("http://inareg.com/APIs/ListMerchantCategories",(Activity) c),MerchantCategories[].class);
        return categs;

    }

    protected void onPostExecute(MerchantCategories[] response) {
        if(response == null) {
            progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        }
        else{
        progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        MerchantCategoriesAdp adp =new MerchantCategoriesAdp(c,R.layout.lst_merchant_categories,response);
        drawerList.setAdapter(adp);
      //  Log.i("INFO", response);
      //  responseView.setText(response);
            }
    }
}
```

This method which i used to initialize a new request and return JSON String

```
    public static String getJsonFrom(final String urlStr, Activity context) {
    final Context c = context;
     final SharedValue value = new SharedValue();
     String result="";

    StringRequest request = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET,urlStr,new Response.Listener<String>(){
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
            value.setResult(response);
        }

    },new  Response.ErrorListener(){

        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            Toast.makeText(c, "No Internet Connection",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });
    Volley.newRequestQueue(c).add(request);
    return value.getResult();
}
```

as you can see that first request 
            EgxServices.getJsonFrom("[http://inareg.com/APIs/RegisterAndroidDevice?registrationID="+regid,(Activity) c](http://inareg.com/APIs/RegisterAndroidDevice?registrationID=%22%20regid,(Activity)%20c));

run successfully but the second one , 
EgxServices.getJsonFrom("[http://inareg.com/APIs/ListMerchantCategories",(Activity) c](http://inareg.com/APIs/ListMerchantCategories%22,(Activity)%20c));
always return null value ...
i need to know why ?????!!!

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
request.setShouldCache(false);
```

before `Volley.newRequestQueue(c).add(request);`

Comment: i also noticed that it return value only in debug and if i pass the response result to  Log.v("sd","Volley Response +++ "+response); inside onResponse

Comment: The problem may be from the way to pass result

Comment: did you try this : request.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(
        MY_SOCKET_TIMEOUT_MS, 
        DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES, 
        DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT));

Comment: i also tried it , but i made sure that the problem in the way to pass the resulted response ,, in SharedValue class --> value.getResult()